# How to get the frame.width during the animation

Tags: ios, animation

I register my View with UISwipeGestureRecognizer to recognize a left or right swipe. And the response operation is:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"slide" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:4];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

CGRect frame = self.sliderImageView.frame;
if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft )
{
    frame.size.width = 0;
    self.sliderImageView.frame = frame;
}
else if (recognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight)
{
    frame.size.width = 199;
    self.sliderImageView.frame = frame;
}

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

If it's possible to get the `self.sliderImageView.frame.width` of the displaying View? Because what I try to do so during the animation using `NSLog(@"%f", self.sliderImageView.frame.size.width)` is either 0 or 199. So is there any methods to get the `frame.width`?

Comment: NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(sliderImageView.frame.size));

Comment: It does not work. The size printed is either {0, 26} or {199, 26}.:(@Suresh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

During an animation, you can access the current value of properties using the view's layer's presentation layer. Include the QuartzCore framework in your project, import the QuartzCore header, and use this:

```
self.sliderImageView.layer.presentationLayer.frame.size.width
```

Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CALayer/presentationLayer).

Comment: Aha, it's great.`CALayer *temp = self.sliderImageView.layer.presentationLayer;
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(temp.frame.size));`

Answer (score 0):

You'll get like this :

```
NSLog(@"%f",self.sliderImageView.frame.size.width);
```

Comment: Not working. I think I've already changed the width, so whatever I do to get the width is the value after changing. It may need some underlying methods to make it.